# How do i have a Dojo checkbox run a command?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I am setting up checkboxes that i would like to enable/disable layers i have on a google earth project using Dojo.  I understand how to create the checkboxes, and select and deselect them.  But how do i use these values, to pass a particular function.  For instance, i have a function that i can run in a script, that will turn on borders on Google Earth, if it is marked true.  I would like to have it set so that if a box is checked, it will be on, otherwise, uncheck it to turn off the borders.  Here is the command to turn them on:

```
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true)
```

Here is the code i am currently using for showing the checkbox in the body of the page:

```
<input id="BorderCheck" name="BorderCheck" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" value="On" checked /><label for="Borders">Turn Borders on/off"</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty suggestion, try:

```
<input id="BorderCheck" 
       name="BorderCheck" 
       dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" 
       value="On" checked 
       onChange="ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, arguments[0]);"
/>
<label for="Borders">Turn Borders on/off</label>
```

Assuming that `ge` is a global variable, of course.

Comment: I will try this in just a moment!